# Using esp32 adc1_get_raw() inside vTaskSuspendAll() leads to assert failed

Tags: esp32, freertos, adc

The program needs to take several consecutive ADC measurements without interruption and the WiFi task interferes with that, that is why the scheduler needs to be suspended. However, I get the following runtime error when I run the code below: `assert failed: xQueueSemaphoreTake queue.c:1554 (!( ( xTaskGetSchedulerState() == ( ( BaseType_t ) 0 ) ) && ( xTicksToWait != 0 ) ))`

```
 vTaskSuspendAll();
 int i1 = adc1_get_raw(ADC1_CHANNEL_7);
 xTaskResumeAll();
```

But I cannot figure out why this happens and how to resolve it.
The stack trace is the following:

```
0x4008307d: panic_abort at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/esp_system/panic.c line 402
0x4008b2a5: esp_system_abort at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/esp_system/esp_system.c line 121
0x400904cd: __assert_func at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/newlib/assert.c line 85
0x4008c259: xQueueSemaphoreTake at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/freertos/queue.c line 1549 (discriminator 1)
0x40084830: lock_acquire_generic at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/newlib/locks.c line 155
0x40084921: _lock_acquire at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/newlib/locks.c line 163
0x400d687a: adc1_rtc_mode_acquire at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/driver/adc_common.c line 445
0x400d6965: adc1_get_raw at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/driver/adc_common.c line 474
```

Example code to reproduce the behavior:

```
#include <driver/adc.h>

void setup() {
  adc1_config_width(ADC_WIDTH_BIT_9);
  adc1_config_channel_atten(ADC1_CHANNEL_7, ADC_ATTEN_DB_11);
  vTaskSuspendAll();
  int i1 = adc1_get_raw(ADC1_CHANNEL_7);
  xTaskResumeAll();
}

void loop() {
  
}
```

(Arduino ESP32 library version 2.0.2 and the same behavior happens with PlatformIO as well)

Comment: Would you mind adding a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code?

Comment: I added a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I suspect that the ADC needs interrupts, tasks or semaphores to work, which won't work when calling `vTaskSuspendAll();`. Is there any reason you don't simply disable wifi/bt or set it to sleep during measurement?

Comment: I tried using the WiFi.setSleep(true); function but it didn't seem to work. I need to measure uninterruptedly for about 200ms and my initial idea was to use one of the cores of the esp32 while the other handles the wifi connectivity. But unfortunately tasks on both cores are suspended by the wifi driver. 
I believe disabling wifi and re-enabling it would require the esp32 to reconnect to wifi which I would avoid if possible. 
The ideal solution would be to suspend the wifi task during the measurement or achieve that only one of the cores is affected when the wifi driver is active.

Comment: Is using esp_wifi_stop() an option? Of course it would be necessary to reauthenticate afterwards. If not, the ideal solution hardware wise would be to use an external ADC to maintain a high measurement accuracy even with wifi enabled.

Comment: It looks as if you are trying to go low-level and temporarily shutdown FreeRTOS. Why not use ADC with DMA? Then it will continuously sample without any need for CPU intervention. So it won't be affected by task switches and interrupts.

Comment: Kudos to Codo. That's precisely what DMA is for.

Comment: Thank you @Codo for the idea. I will look into using DMA. Do you know if it's possible with DMA to read from multiple pins using ADC1?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. See [adc_digi_controller_configure()](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/adc.html#_CPPv429adc_digi_controller_configurePK24adc_digi_configuration_t) and the related struct passed to it.